# sudo Acting Differently on Two Machines - same account

Tags: rhel, sudo

RHEL 8.8 on VMWare (eSXI) on two different VM's (server01 and server02)

So we have an administrative account in our AD "pfsadmin" used for various purposes including stopping and starting database brokers etc. It is a member of the group "progress" among others.

Both machines have this user set up as allowed to use sudo. Both sudoers files are exactly the same.

When I run id on that account I get exactly the same response on both machines.

```
$ id pfsadmin
uid=1682002602(pfsadmin) gid=1682001124(progress) groups=1682001124(progress),1682000520(group policy creator owners),1682000512(domain admins),1682000518(schema admins),1682000513(domain users),1682001106(management),1682001125(wheel),1682001123(sudoers),1682001107(staff),1682000572(denied rodc password replication group)
```

Password file and group files are identical on both machines

However, when I run a "sudo commandname" on machine02, it runs perfectly. When I run the same command on machine01 it prompts for a password every single time.

Relevant portion of the sudoers file below:

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
%progress   ALL=(ALL)   ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
pfsadmin    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL
```

(and keep in mind that the two files are byte for byte identical)

So the million dollar question is: where else can I check to look for the "difference" in the way in which sudo behaves? What other files can I compare between machines that may have some bearing?

TIA

Nigel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run `sudo -l` on both systems as `pfsadmin` and compare the outputs.

Also check `/etc/sudoers.d/` for additional sudoers file snippets.

Comment: Thank you - spot on. Someone had put an additional entry in the sudoers.d that added the entry that broke it. Fixed.